# Packet is received on TCP level but not able to read

Tags: tcpdump, smpp

we are using SMPP protocol for sending messages to SMSC.
When SMSC restarted session, client binded it again successfully
But client unable to get/read further pdu like submit_resp, enquire_resp which SMSC has sent.
We have checked tcp dump using wireshark, 
it  has been found that client receive tcp packet in tcp dump, app not able to read anything, 
In app, we have used Logica smpp lib.
we have checked by putting more logs in logica lib, then it is found that Logica lib doesn't get any thing to read from socket.
Please have comment, which can give more detail direction !!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that when SMSC restarts,

1. The client bound again.
2. The client is not able to read subsequent PDU(s).

Since the question does not give any specific information, I will have to guess what the problem is. I would suggest to check the code for stale com.logica.smpp.Session object(s).